# Javascript - AmCharts hide and show graph using legends

Tags: javascript, graph, amcharts

I am using Amcharts plugins in making a graph. But I am having issues in hiding and showing the graph using legends.

This is my function code:

```
function handleLegendClick( graph ) {
  var chart = graph.chart;
  for( var i = 0; i < chart.graphs.length; i++ ) {
    if ( graph.id == chart.graphs[i].id )
      chart.hideGraph(chart.graphs[i]);
    else 
     chart.showGraph(chart.graphs[i]);
  }

  if (graph.id == chart.graphs['3'].id)
      chart.hideGraph(chart.graphs['4']);

  if (graph.id ==chart.graphs['4'].id)
      chart.hideGraph(chart.graphs['3']);

    chart.validateNow();
  // return false so that default action is canceled
  return true;
}
```

This code is working but my problem is, it hides only one graph and show the graph again when the user click another legend. What I need to do is to hide multiple graphs by clicking it's assigned label text and marker, and when the graph is hidden I should click the same legend to show the hidden graph.

Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description, the default legend behavior does exactly what you're asking for without needing to add your handleClick code. I'm not sure what's the point of it.

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  // ...
  "legend": { }, //default setup
});
```

[Here's an example with multiple graphs.](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/b97b5a6b2d2ff8a6216db1e9fc95444c)